# Rally 2.0 example provided will not load

Tags: rally

So I've recently decided to upgrade to Rally SDK 2.0. I'm using the starter kit and following the directions on the website.  All I've done so far is added:

```
launch: function() {
this.iterationCombobox = this.add({
    xtype: 'rallyiterationcombobox'
});
}
```

To the js file.  Ran the rake command, loaded App.html into a browser. It is blank. According to the website, there should be a small combobox on the top left of the screen.  I don't know what I missed, I assumed the example would work as the website displayed.

*edit*  I should add that this isn't the only thing contained in the HTML file.  I just meant that rake generates an HTML file at the beginning that adds //Add Code Here to the javascript function. I meant that the above code is the only tihng I've changed.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code snippet and it works in my testing. Did you paste the App code into a Custom HTML App in Rally? Or are you running outside of Rally?

If the latter, you'll need to modify the src attribute of the script tag in App.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/sdk.js"></script>
```

So that it contains a fully-qualified reference to the AppSDK2 JS library.

The [AppSDK API Docs](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p4/doc/#) have some good [Examples](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p4/doc/#!/example) of simple starter Apps. The Grid examples are good places to start. You can click on the "View Source" link within any of the Example apps and see the source code.

Comment: I added that lone that you posted, still nothing.The page is just blank, both inside and outside of Rally.

Comment: I'd recommend working with one of the Starter example apps referenced above. If you could post your full App.html code too that would help us to assist you.